# 80s game about running and maintaining a power station

Tags: apple-ii, identify-this-game

Way back in the late 80s there was a game that centered around maintaining and running a power station for the local town. It wasnt particually complex or graphic.. just fun. On the lhs of the screen was some text about what was happening and the required power output the town needed, whilst on the RHS was an internal view of the power station (might have been nuclear). From there you could control the output, rods, pumps etc.

Game I think was on Apple II (but may have actually been on an Apple clone... like Cat Computer from Dick Smith).

Anyone know what this game might be?

Comment: Is it [this one](https://macgui.com/downloads/?file_id=6872)?

Comment: [Scram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scram_(video_game)) was also a nuclear power plant simulator, but for the Atari 800.

Comment: I have a memory of such an simulator for the swedish ABC800 computer -- i in fact had a go in the simulator the same day num 4 reactor in Chernobyl exploded (i should have worked with the basic program i had as a laboration..)

Comment: There was, as I recall, a game on the A][ called Three Mile Island that was more-or-less a simulation of a nuke plant.

Comment: Its not "Nuclear Power Plant" NickWestgate... thought it looks familar. :-)
Scram is very close JimNelson :-)
Think its most likely Three Mile Island .. JeffZeitlin. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Muse's 1979 classic [Three Mile Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Mile_Island_(video_game)) might be it.  It was text and lo-res graphics; there are a bunch of screen shots on [MobyGames](https://www.mobygames.com/game/three-mile-island).

Comment: Whoa. They sure didn't waste any time. I guess sensitivities were different back then. I can't imagine "Corona: The Game" being released in 2020.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Mile_Island_accident), there was little provable harm to humans from the accident. To your other point, consider [this](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-51222796).

Comment: @JörgWMittag No? https://socialdistancegame.com/

Comment: I think its Three Mile Island @fadden and JeffZeitlin  :-)

Comment: There was also one of my all-time favorite SNL skits, "you can never put too much water in a nuclear reactor". All the fun stuff was because Three Mile Island was not (thankfully) Chernobyl or Fukushima (or Coronavirus). You didn't have direct injuries & deaths (arguable cancer later on, but the delay softens the blow, for better or worse). Very different from today's situation.

Answer (score 2):

**Creative Computing Magazine** printed Stephen R. Berggren's [Apple Nuclear Power Plant](https://archive.org/details/creativecomputing-1980-12/page/n131/mode/2up/) simulator in December 1980. There were many variants/developments on this for different platforms, and some added graphics.

There's a playable version of the original at [kevinr/apple-nuclear-power-plant-sim: Stephen R. Berggren's 1980 Apple Nuclear Power Plant sim](https://github.com/kevinr/apple-nuclear-power-plant-sim).

Comment: Loved the old school magazine link Scruss... unfortunately... its not this game :-)

Comment: Nice! You can play the (fixed!) version here: [Three Mile Island (Special Edition)](https://archive.org/details/a2_3_mile_island_special_edition) with [manual](https://archive.org/details/ThreeMileIslandAppleIIManual/mode/2up) for reference